# Is there a program like Filezilla that handles MySQL tables?

Tags: php, mysql, filezilla

I'm looking for a way to use something else than PHPmyadmin. Are there any tools out there that can let me do this?

Comment: For what purpose, filezilla is a file transfer program, are you looking for something to copy databases, or a general purpose database management environment like PHPmyadmin?  Not sure about the reference to FileZilla, very disjointed.

Comment: What does Filezilla, an ftp client, have to do with MySQL tables?  Did you mean phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Right, so Filezilla has nothing to do with databases, but this question did help me track down Workbench when a colleague described it as "Filezilla for databases" and couldn't remember the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll throw a couple more choices at you:

MySQL Workbench - http://wb.mysql.com/ - Developed by the MySQL Team
SQLyog - http://www.webyog.com/en/ - I use the community version of this mostly, the pop-up when you open and close it are a bit annoying but I like the interface more than the others I've tried

Comment: I forgot to mention - both of the ones I mentioned are free; not sure if this is a consideration for you but it's worth mentioning

Answer (score 2):

I use and recommend [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/).

[image]

It also has lots of import/export features that come in handy for backing up and restoring you databases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a program like PuTTY and connect to your server (or just open a command line or terminal if you're testing on localhost) and use `mysql` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are many. Here are the best ones I have found.

On Windows

- [Hedi SQL](http://www.heidisql.com/)
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

On Mac:

- [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)
- [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/)

Other:

1. [DB Ninja](https://www.dbninja.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [DbVisualizer](https://www.dbvis.com/).  It supports a number of databases including MySQL.  It runs on Linux, OS X and Windows.

[image: DbVisualizer Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [dbvis.com](https://www.dbvis.com/images/mainwindow-win7.png))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently using  [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), it's free and you can use it on Linux and Windows. It has a beautiful and very intuitive interface. I use it mainly for database modeling but the server administration tools are great.

Screenshots [here](http://wb.mysql.com/?page_id=35)

Answer (score 0):

[SequelPro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) is great on Mac OS. Then, I use [Navicat](http://www.navicat.com/) on Windows.